# Select all faces below a certain Z value?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, faces, displacement

For example, imagine I have a simple subdivided plane, I use the displace modifier with a heightmap to displace the plane, and now i want to select all the faces below a certain Z value so that I may delete them. How would I go about doing this?

Could weight paint be used to select faces? Because weight paint has a handy gradient option that can be used to select all the lowest parts of a model (just an idea though)

Thanks in advance

Edit: I'll get a little more specific with my problem basically i have a heightmap of a decorative medallion, I want to use the displace modifier on a plane to turn this heightmap 3d, then select the lowest parts, aka the parts of the plane which weren't displaced. I could select all the faces manually, but the heightmap is pretty complex and it would be a lot easier to just select all the lowest faces and delete them. It will not have a backside, but it does not need a backside since it never will be viewed from there. I tried the box select on the side but it mostly just selected the edge pixels.

Comment: This does not sound like a particularly good method to model anything. What is it that you are trying to achieve here? Why don't you use simple box select viewing the model from the side?

Comment: What about applying/previewing in edit mode the modifier and box selecting from the side view?

Comment: i added some more details to my original post to clarify.

Comment: Use either box or lasso select in wireframe mode. The wireframe mode is important otherwise you won't select occluded vertices.

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly gtzkw, thank you!